# WPF Combobox Mouse Over

Tags: wpf, combobox

How can I setup a Combobox Style to make it look like this when mouse is hovering over it?

[image]

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried this:

```xml
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

But it did not work.

Update, this is what I have when I right-click on the combobox:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Blend gave me these colors:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
```

These are the blue colors you are getting.
If you right click the `ComboBox` then `Edit Template -> Edit a Copy...` you should be able to change the color to whatever you want. Look for `MouseOver` entries.

[image: Edit template]

The code can be inserted anywhere you like it. In my example it is inside `<Window.Resources>`:

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
...
</Window.Resources>
```

This is just an example!!

It's a rather big code snippet, but this is the part you want to change.

Comment: +1 I was trying to find these earlier and couldn't. Note: You could do `Transparent` for the color value.

Comment: Tico, where should I insert the code you provided? Also I tried right click on the combobox, there is no "edit" in the menu that pops out

Comment: The code will be provided to you as soon as you edit the template for the `ComboBox`. I'll put a screenshot for you

Comment: I don't see the same right click menu. I updated question to include the screenshot.

Comment: You must be using VS2010? Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe you'll need Expression Blend. In case you don't have it, I paste the entire code at http://pastebin.com/xu2GPUB5